# springboot How to exclude configuration class in dependency dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using a library dependency which contains a `@configuration` class that I need to be ignored.

When I do

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={NeedsToBeExcluded.class})
public class Startup {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Startup.class, args);
}
```

I get the Exception

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes: NeedsToBeExcluded.class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use @ComponentScan to exclude classes:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"package1","package2"},
  excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(
    type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
    value = {ExcludedConfigClass.class})
  })
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.  Does it matter if ExcludedConfigClass resides under one of the basePackages?  Does it matter if ExcludedConfigClass is a @SpringBootApplication?